# What to use instead of wp_kses() in user output

Tags: security, escaping, wp-kses

I need some help here.

While developing a theme, I want to make sure there are no security issues. So all dynamic data must be correctly escaped for the context where it is rendered.

I know how to escape the following:

- If 'echo' in the attribute, use `esc_attr`
- If 'echo' in class attribute, use `sanitize_html_class`
- If 'echo' in plain text, use `esc_html`
- If 'echo' in translation, use `esc_html__`, `esc_html_e`, `esc_attr_e`, etc

But there're two areas in which I am not sure what to do.

1. What escaping should I use if user output may contain some html tags, like 'em' or 'strong'?

Example:

```
<?php $subtitle = get_post_meta($post_id,'subtitle', true); ?>
<h3 class="subtitle"><?php echo $subtitle; ?></h3>
```

Note that "wp_kses is an expensive function, so it should only be run when data is saved, not displayed"
Proof [here](http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/what-to-use-instead-of-wp_kses/165526)

2. What escaping should I use to output CSS styles?

Example:

```
<style type="text/css"><?php echo $css; ?></style>
```

Comment: From my point of view, allow or not certain HTML tags is data validation, which should be done when data is saved, not when data is displayed. Data should be validated and sanitized always when it is saved, that is rule number 1 on security.

Comment: Thank for your reply. However, according to this article https://vip.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/the-importance-of-escaping-all-the-things/ data should be validated and sanitized always and not only when it's saved but rendered as well.

Comment: I totally agree with the article you posted but you need to understand the difference between scaping and data validation/sanitization. As I said, what you are trying to do with the subtitle is data validation: you need to validate the data against valid values and that should be done when the data is saved, using `wp_kses` seems good. Anyway, if you want to escape only certain HTML tags on data output, I think you need to go with [DOM manipulation class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Not sure what to do when printing CSS styles, `esc_html` could be enough to print CSS rules.

Answer (score 4):

Let's go and see what would core do.

In `default-filters.php` here is what content output passes through:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'        );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars'      );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

None of these are dedicated security/escaping functions really.

It is similar for comments, which come from random visitors altogether and not even semi-trusted site authors:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wptexturize'            );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'convert_chars'          );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'make_clickable',      9 );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'force_balance_tags', 25 );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'convert_smilies',    20 );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpautop',            30 );
```

In a nutshell it is *reasonably* trustworthy, having been scrubbed on submissions and coming back from database.

Comment: As I understand you suggest us just leave it and not to do anything. Am I right? :)

Comment: I am suggesting that **if** you are sanitizing the particular inputs on save to the same degree as WP does then not escaping them on output is an acceptable practice in my opinion.

Comment: @Rarst that is also my point, sanitizing on save, that is what I was trying to explain in the comments.

Comment: It does not occurr to me that  Wordpress does sanitize posts on save. At least not for admins. That is why you can add an alert script to your post body and simply save and display that, as long you are an admin or user with unfiltered HTML post caps.  You can't do this as editor, for example.

It is a common misconception to believe that WP does not escape the_content because it is sanitised on input: it is not! The reason they do not escape it, is that if they would, you couldn't even add a contact form to your pages or posts.